# Casting between the two parents of a multi inherited class with virtual functions leads to weird behaviors

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, vtable

Below is the code. I don't understand why it behaves like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class FooInterface {
public:
    virtual ~FooInterface() = default;
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class BarInterface {
public:
    virtual ~BarInterface() = default;

    virtual void Bar() = 0;
};

class Concrete : public FooInterface, public BarInterface {
public:
    void Foo() override { cout << "Foo()" << endl; }
    void Bar() override { cout << "Bar()" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    Concrete c;
    c.Foo();
    c.Bar();

    FooInterface* foo = &c;
    foo->Foo();

    BarInterface* bar = (BarInterface*)(foo);
    bar->Bar(); // Prints "Foo()" - WTF?
}
```

The last statement bar->Bar() prints "Foo()" which confused me. This comes from the following blog:
https://shaharmike.com/cpp/vtable-part4/. Basically it relates to structure of the vtable of the class and how compiler handles the cast between two parent classes of a multi inherited class with virtual functions. Can anybody help me understand this?

Comment: BarInterface* bar = dynamic_cast<BarInterface*>(foo);

Comment: @MinorThreat BarInterface* bar = dynamic_cast<BarInterface*>(foo); prints "Bar()" but my code prints "Foo()". So the the C type cast is not doing dynamic cast.

Comment: Your problem requires runtime analysis of object's dynamic type. C style cast doesn't work here since it just turns type check off and returns the same pointer which points to FooInterface sub-object.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `(BarInterface*)(foo);`, you're lying to the compiler.  You're telling it that `foo` is really a pointer to `BarInterface`, so the compiler will believe you.  Since it isn't, you get Undefined Behavior when you attempt to dereference the pointer.  Discussing how a compiled program behaves in the presence of Undefined Behavior is often pointless.

In this case, the way your compiler has populated the vtables, the entry for `FooInterface::Foo` appears to be in the same place as the entry for `BarInterface::Bar`.  As a result, when you call `bar->Bar()`, the compiler looks into the `FooInterface` vtable, finds the entry for `FooInterface::Foo`, and calls that.  If the class layouts would be different, or the function signatures different, far more serious consequences would ensue.

The solution, of course, is to use a `dynamic_cast` which can perform the necessary sideways cast.

Comment: The cast is not (always) undefined behavior. Assuming that the alignment requirement for `BarInterface` is not stricter than for `FooInterface`, the cast is allowed (otherwise it is undefined behavior, but, considering that the types are basically the same, it's probably not the case). The resulting `BarInterface*` exists, but doesn't actually point to a `BarInterface` object. Casting it back to `FooInterface*` will successfully retrieve the original,  and it's the attempt to dereference it inside the `->` that is undefined.

Comment: @HTNW Good point.  I didn't think about when exactly the UB kicked in.